What does GB Shaw mean when he says "like the butcher's wife in the old catch" here?

The belief in the inheritance of acquired characteristics was virtually universal until the mid-1880s. Only after Darwin’s death in 1882 were doubts starting to be raised, at first by one lone voice in the wilderness, the German biologist August Weismann. In 1887, Weismann embarked on his most notorious—and most often ridiculed—research project, the one that George Bernard Shaw lampooned as the “three blind mice” experiment. “Weismann began to investigate the point by behaving like the butcher’s wife in the old catch,” Shaw explained. “He got a colony of mice, and cut off their tails. Then he waited to see whether their children would be born without tails. They were not. He then cut off the children’s tails, and waited to see whether the grandchildren would be born with at least rather short tails. They were not, as I could have told him beforehand. So with the patience and industry on which men of science pride themselves, he cut off the grandchildren’s tails, too, and waited, full of hope, for the birth of curtailed great-grandchildren. But their tails were quite up to the mark, as any fool could have told him beforehand. Weismann then gravely drew the inference that acquired habits cannot be transmitted.”

What do the words in bold mean in the text?

"Weismann began to investigate the point by behaving like the butcher's wife in the old catch."


Source: Through the Language Glass: Why the World Looks Different in Other Languages by Guy Deutscher

@Xanne presumably Shaw was familiar with a variant of those words where the wife was married to a butcher rather than a farmer.  Sai Deepak: see sense 15 at Wiktionary: (countable, music) A type of humorous round in which the voices gradually catch up with one another; usually sung by men and often having bawdy lyrics. or, since that's not quite correct, 5 at Merriam-Webster: a round for three or more voices.

Thank you all! This answers my question.

@Xanne Please write an answer in the answer box. Comments are not for answers.

Surely this is a literature question not an English language question? Nursery rhymes are still literature.

it's a language question because the OP is asking for the meaning of "old catch", used in this example I  did not know it also carried the meanings mentioned by Xanne and @phoog. A proper answer should be posted, I would bet that the post would attract a lot of attention.

@StuartF forgot to ping you. The question is asking about meaning, the OP never mentions the nursery rhyme, maybe they were already familiar with it but only knew the "farmer's wife" version, maybe not. It wouldn't make much difference because it is the expression "old catch" which caught their attention, and that is not a question about literature.

@mari I didn't know it either, and I didn't find it in the first dictionary results I looked at. I agree that it deserves a proper answer.

I would also note the association of a catch with the three rounds of tail cutting by Weismann.

OED

Catch (n.) 3. Music. Originally: a short, simple song for three or more unaccompanied voices, each singing the same melody, the
second singer beginning the first line as the first goes on to the
second line, and so with each successive singer; a round.
1978 They sang in round, and showed no sign of stopping, an Italian
catch. I. Murdoch, Sea 312
2009 Glees and catches were often accompanied by piano or instrumental
ensemble. Journal of British Studies vol. 48 225

When formally sung, this is the pattern that (what is now a nursery rhyme) is presented.

Yes, I had completely forgotten that "Three blind mice" can be sung in a staggered manner, one singer after the other or "[in] a catch"?

I've never seen "to sing something in a catch". It may be possible but I suspect it would have to be  "to sing something as a catch"

@Greybeard: ...writing out the song as it would have been sung in a catch. - Robert Armin and Shakespeare's Performed Songs (2017). But I'd normally call it a round anyway.

@FumbleFingers Yes, that did cross my mind. It's a question of what "in" means. "The words appear in (within) a catch" is fine, but "I sang the song in a catch" I suspect is not idiomatic as it is a style. (If you sub "a catch" for "R&B", it may help.

@Greybeard Where do you see that phrase? The phrase in the quoted passage is "in the old catch", which means "in the old song".

@Barmar. If I understand you rightly, then "Weismann began to investigate the point by behaving like the butcher’s wife in the old catch,” --> Weismann began to investigate the point by behaving like the butcher’s wife, who is a character in the old catch, and who took vigorous action.” I was commenting on the other meaning of "in" as in "He sang in a high voice."

Of course. But since that's not a logical interpretation of "wife in the old catch", we don't need to say so explicitly.

Obviously, I did not understand you rightly... It is possible that I am being dense, but I don't understand your point at all.

@Greybeard: "how it would be sung in a catch" sounds perfectly idiomatic to me, even though knowing what "catch" means there is at the margins of my vocabulary (because I'd call it a "round" anyway). I wouldn't distinguish between "in a catch" being precisely equivalent to "within an actual catch" or "in the style of a [hypothetical] catch", since in practice the meaning would be the same either way. As I expected, sung in a round also occurs with exactly the same meaning.

The only thing I remember about the few "music" classes I was in at age 11 is the teacher divided us into several groups, we sang London's Burning, with each group starting when the teacher pointed to us (as the preceding group reached the end of one line). I quite liked the effect, but we never did it again, so I think after a few weeks I used to skive off round the bike sheds when we had music lessons.

This is the canonical answer. ;)

@PM2Ring: This answer is entirely correct, but it’s only half of the explanation for readers who don’t already know the song in question — Xanne’s answer gives the other half.

@PLL: No, Xanne's answer is effectively irrelevant. It's not that easy to find this meaning of catch - you certainly won't get it just by googling the single word, and even after googling define catch you'd probably have a lot more work to get the relevant definition. But googling three blind mice will tell you everything you could possibly want to know about it (apart from, obviously, the fact that it's one of a severely restricted subcategory of nursery rhymes once sometimes called "catches" :)

@mdfst13: No. To someone who does not know that "three blind mice" is a nursery rhyme, they will immediately discover everything they need to know about it on the Google homepage, simply by searching for the term. That's not the case with this particular (rare / dated / archaic) sense of the word catch. No matter how many pages of Google results for catch you scrolled through, I doubt you would ever catch sight of one containing the relevant definition. Bear in mind preceding text includes the one that George Bernard Shaw lampooned as the “three blind mice” experiment.

Yes, but why would they search that instead of "butcher's wife" which is in the same sentence.

It’s an English nursery rhyme.

“ Three blind mice. Three blind mice. See how they run. See how they run. They all ran after the farmer's wife, Who cut off their tails with a carving knife. Did you ever see such a sight in your life As three blind mice?” https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Blind_Mice

The nursery rhyme is the “catch,” as explained in another answer.
The passage causes problems for readers unfamiliar with the nursery rhyme. People familiar with it can easily infer a workable meaning of “catch.” The catch is “old” (like an old joke) because most readers are assumed to know the rhyme.

...the butcher's wife… according to GB Shaw.

There were versions where the butcher's  wife cut off the tails.
